# Run script as other user

Tags: shell, permissions

I try to kill a service as a other user. I login as a user "usernoroot" and kill a service of a root user "userroot"!

Therefore I have a killscript.sh in the folder of "usernoroot" like:

```
#!/bin/sh
kill -9 $1
```

and make this script executable:

```
chown root:root /home/usernoroot/killscript.sh
chmod 755 /home/usernoroot/killscript.sh
```

Now I try to run `./killscript.sh <pid>` but getting:

```
./killscript.sh: 2: kill: Operation not permitted
```

What can I do to run this script successfully?

EDIT

I have installed sudo:

```
apt-get install sudo
```

add my user to group sudo

```
adduser usernoroot sudo
```

and add the script "killscript.sh to the sudoers

```
nano /etc/sudoers
usernoroot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/usernoroot/killscript.sh
```

Now I can execute `./killscript.sh 222` to quit the process with the id 222 without any PW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are running the script as `usernoroot` that mean you don't have the right permeation to kill any process you don't own, so for killing any process on the system you can use `sudo` tool to run your script as `root` user:

```
sudo ./killscript.sh <pid>
```

There is another way to do that but **I don't recommend it**, it will make a serious security problem, and if it used in a wrong way it will make a big problems.

use a `setUID` on `kill` tool but you have to be root:

```
chmod 4755 /bin/kill
```

then **any one** can run the `kill` tool as a root user, **I don't recommend this way**

Comment: I'm on Debian without sudo?!

Comment: @fteinz I edited my answer, you can install sudo on Debian